# How to filter through the list/retrieve function on Model ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

Anyone know How can I implement a search filter on list/retrieve function to a viewset?

I'm trying to use DRF Searh-filter on ViewSet but it's not working (it doesn't return the object filtered).

What I want to return is something like -->  /store/1/locker/1/controller?controller={name_controller}

view.py

```
class ControllerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ControllerSerializer
    queryset = Controller.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['controller']

    def list(self, request, store_pk=None, locker_pk=None):
        queryset = Controller.objects.filter(locker__store=store_pk, locker=locker_pk)
        serializer = ControllerSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, store_pk=None, locker_pk=None):
        queryset = Controller.objects.filter(pk=pk, locker=locker_pk, locker__store=store_pk)
        locker = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = ControllerSerializer(locker, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: did you set any filter backends in your settings? and how did you exactly called the API to filter/search the results?

Comment: Yes I did as specified on DRF documentation... Through the url as shown above is the same but doesnt return the objects, the url change but does not work

Answer (score 1):

You set a filter backend, but then you overrode the code that would have called it (`list()`, `retrieve()`).

Seems like the only reason you overrode those methods is to filter the queryset by store and locker pks. This can be done in one place to affect all requests and without breaking existing code.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    locker_pk = self.kwargs["locker_pk"]  # named parameters in url appear in self.kwargs
    store_pk = self.kwargs["store_pk"]
    return super().get_queryset().filter(locker=locker_pk, locker__store=store_pk)
```

And that's it. DRF will call this method to get queryset, filter it as configured, and serialize the data with your serializer automatically. No need to manually implement what's already provided.

**Note**: ensure your pks are valid with regex. You don't want your app to crash if someone requests `/store/x/locker/y/controller`, right? The regex should be `\d+` for any integer.